# jquery ajax and setinterval defined inside function

Tags: jquery

I have a function to constantly send the request, but the time intervals need to change depending on what my function returns.
Calling the script, which I returned in the JSON variable cas interval in seconds and by the need to change the interval variables of this function. Could someone advise me how to do this? And if things do not return anything, so that sent popžadavek again.

Thanks a lot

```
function dotaz(){
     //var cas
    $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "loader.php",
     data: "promenna=1&promt=3&p="+Math.random(),
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(jdata){
        $("#loader").html(jdata.promenna);
          if(jdata.chyba == 0){
           $("#loader").css({'background-color' : '#B90000'});
          }
          if(jdata.chyba == 1){
           $("#loader").css({'background-color' : 'green'});
          }
          var cas = jdata.cas*1000;
     },
     error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){     
                    if(xhr.status == 404) {
                     $("#loader").html("Soubor nenalezen");
                    }
                    if(xhr.status == 400) {
                     $("#loader").html("Špatný požadavek");
                    }
                    if(xhr.status == 403) {
                     $("#loader").html("Přístup zamítnut");
                    }
                    if(xhr.status == 500) {
                     $("#loader").html("Chyba serveru");
                    }
     }   
     });
     setTimeout(function(){dotaz();}, 2000);   
   }   
   dotaz();
```

i need

```
setTimeout(function(){dotaz();}, cas);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you trying to create a loop and after the ajax returns you want to have a timeout for 2000 ms in your case. I would do it like this:

```
function dotaz(cas){
     setTimeout(function(){
         $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "loader.php",
         data: "promenna=1&promt=3&p="+Math.random(),
         dataType: "json",
         success: function(jdata){
            $("#loader").html(jdata.promenna);
              if(jdata.chyba == 0){
               $("#loader").css({'background-color' : '#B90000'});
              }
              if(jdata.chyba == 1){
               $("#loader").css({'background-color' : 'green'});
              }
              var new_cas = jdata.cas*1000;
              dotaz(new_cas);
         },
         error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){     
                        if(xhr.status == 404) {
                         $("#loader").html("Soubor nenalezen");
                        }
                        if(xhr.status == 400) {
                         $("#loader").html("Špatný požadavek");
                        }
                        if(xhr.status == 403) {
                         $("#loader").html("Prístup zamítnut");
                        }
                        if(xhr.status == 500) {
                         $("#loader").html("Chyba serveru");
                        }
                        setTimeout(function(){dotaz();}, 5000);
         }   
         });
      }, cas);
   }   
   dotaz(1000)
```

Just time out before you do the request

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, its right?

```
   function dotaz(){
     //var cas;
     $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "loader.php",
     data: "promenna=1&promt=3&p="+Math.random(),
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(jdata){
        $("#loader").html(jdata.promenna);
          if(jdata.chyba == 0){
           $("#loader").css({'background-color' : '#B90000'});
          }
          if(jdata.chyba == 1){
           $("#loader").css({'background-color' : 'green'});
          }
          var cas = jdata.cas*1000;
          setTimeout(function(){dotaz();}, cas);
     },
     error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){     
                    if(xhr.status == 404) {
                     $("#loader").html("Soubor nenalezen");
                    }
                    if(xhr.status == 400) {
                     $("#loader").html("Špatný požadavek");
                    }
                    if(xhr.status == 403) {
                     $("#loader").html("Přístup zamítnut");
                    }
                    if(xhr.status == 500) {
                     $("#loader").html("Chyba serveru");
                    }
                    setTimeout(function(){dotaz();}, 5000);
     }   
     });   
   }   
   dotaz()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, it looks functional.
I just wanted to ask, how long the script waits for a response. Suppose I have a script that will perform 50s - Sleep (50), and Ajax will always wait for a reply php file, which has given time, how long to be repeated. I would still need to treat, when to get a response from the script in some time, maybe 30 seconds to call the function again and somewhere write popřípadně timeout error.

Code:

```
<script>
   function dotaz(idecko,cas){
     setTimeout(function(){
     $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "loader.php",
     data: "promenna="+idecko+"&promt=3&p="+Math.random(),
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(jdata){
        $("#hlavicka"+idecko).html(jdata.promenna);
        $("#blok"+idecko).html(jdata.data);
        if(jdata.stav == 0) { $("#box"+idecko).removeClass('err war').addClass('rdy'); }
        if(jdata.stav == 1) { $("#box"+idecko).removeClass('err rdy').addClass('war'); }
        if(jdata.stav == 2) { $("#box"+idecko).removeClass('rdy war').addClass('err'); }

        var new_cas = jdata.cas*1000;
        dotaz(idecko,new_cas);
     },
     error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){

                    if(xhr.status == 404) {
                     $("#paticka"+idecko).html("Soubor nenalezen");
                    }
                    if(xhr.status == 400) {
                     $("#paticka"+idecko).html("Špatný požadavek");
                    }
                    if(xhr.status == 403) {
                     $("#paticka"+idecko).html("Přístup zamítnut");
                    }
                    if(xhr.status == 500) {
                     $("#paticka"+idecko).html("Chyba serveru");
                    }                  
                    setTimeout(function(){dotaz(idecko);}, cas);
     }   
     });
     }, cas);


        $('#info'+idecko).hover(
          function () {
           $('#udalost'+idecko).css({'display' : 'block'});
           },
          function () {
           $('#udalost'+idecko).css({'display' : 'none'});
           }
        );

   }   

  </script>
```

and call this script:

```
<script>dotaz(2,0);</script>
```

2 is for div id 2 and 0 to set the first timeout to 0 to do it immediately.